# How to set visual graph attributes for Gephi in booggie 2?

Tags: graph, graph-visualization, gephi, booggie

booggie saves graphs in the GraphML format which can also be opened in the graph visualization tool Gephi.

Is there a way to define the visual appearance of nodes in Gephi with attributes that are accessible in booggie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **nodes**, the following attributes are directly understood by Gephi:

Position:

- x:double
- y:double
- z:double

Watch out: If you use these attributes, the layouters can't modify the position of the nodes anymore

Color:

- r:int
- g:int
- b:int

Label:

- label:string

Regarding **edges**, I don't know. The only thing I know is that edges can have a *weight* attribute that impacts the thicknes of edges.